# Powershell io.streamreader "-context" equivalent command

Tags: .net, powershell

I am using the below code in PowerShell to collect relevant data from a large txt file.

```
$sr = new-object System.io.streamreader(get-item c:\test.txt)

while (($line = $sr.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if ($line -match "data") { $line } 
}

$sr.Dispose()
```

This works well however it would be useful if there were an equivalent to PowerShell's `select-string -context 1,0` to be able to get the line above as well as the matched line.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Just add `$prev_line = $line` after `if ...` and change output to `{ $prev_line, $line }`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  I may have misunderstood but I typed:        if ($prev_line = $line -match "data") { $prev_line, $line } and this almost works but I get True rather than the actual data returned.  Can you advise where I typed wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Reposted as an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only one previous line, the following will suffice:

```
$sr = new-object System.io.streamreader(get-item c:\test.txt)

while (($line = $sr.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if ($line -match "data") { $prev_line, $line }
    $prev_line = $line
}

$sr.Dispose()
```